# NON Equi Join on more than 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to fetch out records from left table only those records which are not in right table. I have near about 5000 records in the left table. Similarly, the same thing is need to be done on more than 3-4 tables. I have to find out records from first table that are not in rest of my 3-4 tables. The same primary or foreign key concept is working their.

My first attempt taking two tables fetch out 5,70,000 records from original 5k records. Repeating the record.

```
SELECT m.* FROM members m, pinnumber p where p.pinmemberid != m.memberid
```

My second attempt also made my-sql browser hang.

```
SELECT m.* FROM members m
LEFT JOIN pinnumber p ON p.pinmemberid != m.memberid
LEFT JOIN customer c ON m.memberid != c.memberid
```

My third attempt is also making a lot of time

```
SELECT * FROM members m
         WHERE 1=1 AND AND not exists ( select 1 from pinnumber p where 1=1 And
         p.pinmemberid = m.memberid AND p.pinproductid LIKE '%Remit%')
         AND not exists ( select 1 from customer c where 1=1 and c.card_name is not null AND m.memberid = c.memberid )
```

Please suggest me what to do with this. If I need to put non-equi join on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will try to join the first table `members` with tables `pinnumber` and `customer`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM
  members m
  LEFT JOIN pinnumber p ON p.pinmemberid = m.memberid
  LEFT JOIN customer c ON m.memberid = c.memberid
WHERE p.pinmemberid is null and c.memberid is null
```

since we are using a `left join`, the query will return all rows of members but if the join doesn't succeed `pinmemberid` and `memberid` will be `null`. The rows in which those values are `null` are the ones that doesn't exist in the right tables. You might want to use OR instead of AND.

If you use a join with `!=` condition, you will get all rows of the first table multiplied for all rows of the second table, except the ones that have the same id.

Another way to get the same result is this:

```
SELECT members.*
FROM members
WHERE
  memberid not in (select pinmembedid from pinnumber)
  and memberid not in (select memberid from customer)
```

(substitute AND with OR if you wish). NOT IN clause might be a little slower, but it's easier to understand.

Comment: I am using first solution but query is completely slow. IS there any way to make it more fast.

Comment: @Sankalp instead of selecting `m.*` you could select only the fileds that you need. And you can consider adding indexes on `m.memberid`, `p.pinmemberid` and `c.memberid`

Answer (score 0):

By the way, what you were trying to do is:

```
SELECT m.* FROM members m
LEFT JOIN pinnumber p ON p.pinmemberid = m.memberid
LEFT JOIN customer c ON m.memberid = c.memberid
where p.pinmemberid is null and c.pinmemberid is null
```

The `left join` produces NULL values when there are no records in the right table.  You can filter for these after the join.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this command will produce your desired output..

```
SELECT m.* FROM members m LEFT JOIN pinnumber p ON p.pinmemberid = m.memberid where m.memberid is null;
```